# Find the vertex C in an Isosceles triangle.

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

There are two vertices A=(2,-2) and B=(6,0) in an isosceles triangle ABC and it's area is 20. How to find the vertex C?

I have used AB as the base of triangle,and I've found its length, I also have found the midpoint of AB and the high from the midpoint to the vertex C. But I don't have any idea of how continue and find vertex C. Any suggestions for me???

Comment: Is the length of $AB = \sqrt 20$? If yes, its altitude $= ... = 2\sqrt 20$

Comment: No, AB=2sqrt5 and its altitude is 4sqrt5

Comment: Note that $2\sqrt5$ is the same as $\sqrt 20$

Comment: Then, the third vertex is at the intersection of (1) the normal through (M), the midpoint of AB and (2) the circle with M as center and radius $= 2\sqrt 20$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you better understand the question, I add the following picture.

[image]

Can you tell how many answers are there? Can you explain why $\triangle ABC_3$ and $\triangle ABC_4$ are not qualified candidates? From that we confirm AB cannot be used as a leg of the issosceles triangle.

Comment: Yeah, I completely understand. Thank u so much. I wasn't that hard but I got stuck in it

Comment: @FloridaKurtaj Good!. Glad to see that helps..